# Adding attributes to input element in Handlebars (used with Ember.JS 1.0)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Let's say I have something like:

```
{{input value=someModel }}
```

And then I want to add the simple `required` HTML 5 attribute to the input.

How would I do that?

---

Note that I tried the following variations without success:

```
{{input value=someModel required }} <!-- doesn't parse -->

{{input value=someModel required='required' }} <!-- doesn't render the attribute -->

{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=someModel 
    required='required' }} <!-- doesn't render the attribute -->

<input required {{bindAttr value=someModel}}
     /> <!-- doesn't update the model, as expected -->
```

---

**Update:** This question was for Ember 1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To globally add support for additional attributes you can reopen Ember.TextField

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html

Comment: This is horrible! (which is not your fault, thanks for pointing at it) - Any idea why it's like that? and whether there is a way to make it open for whatever I add?

Comment: Not all browsers support `required`, so the framework ships with a minimal set, letting developers add additional attributes if they know they will target only browsers that support it.

Comment: This might be a topic for Discourse, but really, I just think there is no point/benefit in limiting what the user can do with their markup (as long as it's not code, e.g. not Handlebars expressions). I'm guessing this is a side effect of some design limitation in the library, if it's meant to be this way as a feature, that'd be nothing but adding friction IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Ember version 1.5.1 and required="required" seems to work fine now.  This markup:

```
{{input class="form-control" value=firstName autofocus="autofocus" required="required"}}
```

...renders this:

```
<input id="ember392" class="ember-view ember-text-field form-control" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" type="text">
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to add support to the required attribute:

```
Ember.TextSupport.reopen({  
    attributeBindings: ["required"]  
})
```

Then in your view:

```
{{view Ember.TextField required="required"}}
```