# How to use jquery-validation on emberjs properly?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, jquery-validate, emblem.js

I am trying to create a simple validation to require name (will add more validations later). The app an ember app, and we want to use [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

I am having trouble just to get a basic validation running. This is what I have:

```
//index.html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

... 
//body and such//
...

<script>
  $('#salesForm').validate();
</script>

</body>
```

Inside a component, say sales-form:

```
//app/components/sales-form/template.emblem

form id="salesForm"
  ...
  .form-group
    label Some Sales Info
      = input type="text" disabled=false value=salesNumber placeholder="Sales Number" class="form-control" required

  button{action: 'clickNSave'}
  ...
```

This gives me a build error, because emblem does not recognize `required` on the input.

How can I create a simple validation using jquery-validation on ember app that uses emblem for template?

Additional question, is my validation on `index.html` correct, to run the validation at the very end, right before closing body tag? If not, where is the best way to insert `$('#someForm').validate();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This gives me a build error, because emblem does not recognize required on the input.

[What about `required="required"` or `required=required`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008763/594235)  Otherwise, I have no idea how you're supposed to add this attribute using Ember.js.

> ... to run the validation...

You are not "running" validation.  You are *"initializing"* the jQuery Validate plugin on your form.

> ...  at the very end, right before closing body tag? If not, where is the best way to insert `$('#someForm').validate();`?

`$('#someForm').validate()` simply gets called inside [a DOM ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and it doesn't matter if it's at the top, bottom, or anywhere else, as long as it's called ***after*** you include jQuery and the plugin.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

....

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {   // ensures DOM is fully constructed
        $('#someForm').validate();   // initialize the plugin on #someForm
    });
</script>
```

Otherwise, if you put in the `head` *without* a DOM ready handler, the `form` is not yet rendered in the DOM and your call to `.validate()` will fail.

> How can I create a simple validation using jquery-validation on ember app that uses emblem for template?

I don't see where you ever assign a `name` attribute to the `input` element.  The jQuery Validate plugin [mandates that any form element being validated must contain a unique `name` attribute](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations).

```
= input type="text" name="sales_number" required="required" disabled=false value=salesNumber placeholder="Sales Number" class="form-control"
```

Refer to [the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) as well as [the SO wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for more information on correct usage of this plugin.